# How to repeat Await multiple times?

Tags: scala, future

I'm new to Scala.
I want to retry `code1` only if it timeout. If another error occurs, I'll handle it in another way. If timeout, I want to try again, for example, 3 times. What is the proper way to doing this?

I'm not sure if using something like `code2` is the best way of doing this on Scala. Maybe there are already something better. Is there some cleaner way for breaking? Should I use Await.ready instead of result?

Im also not sure if I should use Await.ready or Await.result.

code1:

```
Await.result(myMethod(), Duration(120, "seconds"))
```

code2:

```
breakable {
  for(_ <- 0 to 3) {
    Try(Await.result(myMethod(), Duration(120, "seconds"))) match {
      case Success(value) => {
        // do something
        break()
      }
       case Failure(_) => // how can I now if it is timeout?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Should rather compose future than await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to apply the following approach for `repeating evaluation`.

The following snippet defines a generic `retry` method: this method takes in an argument, evaluates it within a `try - catch` block, and re-executes it on failure with a maximum number of attempts.

Making `retry` take a `by-name parameter` is what allows it to repeat evaluation of the `myMethod block` where necessary.

```scala
object Test {

  def retry[T](max: Int)(f: => T): T = {
    var tries = 0
    var result: Option[T] = None
    while (result == None) {
      try {
        result = Some(f)
      }
      catch {
        case e: Throwable => tries += 1
        if (tries > max) throw e
        else {
          println(s"failed, retry #$tries")
        }
      }
    }
    result.get
  }

  def myMethod(n: Int): Int = {
    val num = scala.util.Random.nextInt(10)
    if(n < num) throw new Exception
    else num
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(retry(max = 5){myMethod(3)})
/*
failed, retry #1
failed, retry #2
3
*/
    println(retry(max = 5){myMethod(-1)})
/*
failed, retry #1
failed, retry #2
failed, retry #3
failed, retry #4
failed, retry #5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception
*/
  }
}
```

**NOTE**
`myMethod` function could take a new parameter timeout to introduce some time limit for each function call.

```
  def myMethod(n: Int, timeout: Long): Int = {
    var num = scala.util.Random.nextInt(10)

    val current = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var running = System.currentTimeMillis()
    while (running - current <= timeout && n < num) {
      num = scala.util.Random.nextInt(10)
      running = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
    println(s"time goes on ${running - current}")
    if(n < num) throw new Exception
    else num
  }

// retry function doesn't change
println(retry(5){myMethod(5,5000/*five seconds*/)})
/*
time goes on 5001
failed, retry #1
time goes on 5001
1
*/
println(retry(5){myMethod(-1,5000/*five seconds*/)})
/*
time goes on 5001
failed, retry #1
time goes on 5001
failed, retry #2
time goes on 5001
failed, retry #3
time goes on 5001
failed, retry #4
time goes on 5001
failed, retry #5
time goes on 5001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception
*/
```

Comment: How could I add that 2 minutes limit for each try?

Comment: I think, you could put some delay in `myMethod` function, see the NOTE

Answer (score 3):

Waiting on a `Future` makes the whole `Future`-thing rather pointless. That being said, there are 3 situations that should be handled:

1. all attempts time out
2. a non-time-out failure
3. a `Future` completes successfully

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await, TimeoutException}
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

//            v--max number of attempts
LazyList.fill(4)(Try(Await.result(myMethod(), 120.seconds)))
  .dropWhile{case Failure(_:TimeoutException) => true
             case _ => false
  }.headOption.fold{
    //every attempt timed out
  }{
    case Success(value) => //do something
    case Failure(ex:Throwable) => //ex is non-timeout exception
  }
```

Note: `LazyList` is a Scala 2.13.x collection. Every element in the list is evaluated only if/when it's needed, so if the 1st one succeeds then none of the other futures will be launched.

Answer (score 2):

You could use recursion to implement a simple retry mechanism. Matching on the `TimeoutException` failure will allow you to deal specifically with the timeout case.

Here is an example below, with the assumption that `myMethod` returns a Future[String]:

```
def myMethod(): Future[String] = ???

val maxAttempts = 3

def retryOnTimeout(attempt: Int = 0): String = {
  Try(Await.result(myMethod(), Duration(120, "seconds"))) match {
    case Success(result) => result
    case Failure(_: TimeoutException) if attempt < maxAttempts => retryOnTimeout(attempt  + 1)
    case Failure(err) => throw err
  }
}
```

`retryOnTimeout` could be made more generic to allow it to be used in more than one place, with the function being passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Nice solution.  It might be useful to add a default `Failure(_: TimeoutException)` case to report `max attempts exceeded` before the catch-all `Failure`.